# How to use issparse function?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

A sparse matrix is a matrix in which most of the elements are zero. By contrast, if most of the elements are non-zero then the matrix is considered dense. 
Matrix `A` will be sparse when the number of zero-valued elements divided by the total number of elements is greater than 0.5.

I am using built-in function `issparse` to check the sparsity of the matrix but this function give `0` all times.

How to fix this code?

```
A = [0 0 0; 0 1 0; 1 0 0]; % Matrix-A
S = issparse(A); % Checking Matrix-A is sparse  
if S == 1
   disp('Matrix-A is Sparse Matrix\n')
else
   disp('Matrix-A is Dense Matrix\n')
end
```

The output is:

> Matrix-A is Dense Matrix

Why?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of [`issparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/issparse.html) (emphasis mine):

> `TF = issparse(S)` returns logical 1 (`true`) if the **storage class** of `S` is `sparse` and logical 0 (`false`) otherwise.

What you call a sparse matrix in Mathematics is not necessarily be a sparse matrix in MATLAB. In MATLAB, even a matrix with all zeros can be a dense matrix and a matrix with all non-zeros can be a sparse matrix. However, the purpose of sparse matrices in MATLAB is reducing the amount of required memory by only storing non-zero elements and their indices. Read the documentation ([*here*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html)) to understand more on creating sparse matrices.

Examples:

- The following `A` matrix is sparse:

  ```
   A = sparse([1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1]);

  >> issparse(A)    
  ans =    
    logical    
     1
  ```
- The following `B` matrix is dense:

  ```
  B = [0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0];

  >> issparse(B)    
  ans =    
    logical    
     0
  ```

So, what you have in your workspace is a dense matrix. Your expected result can be obtained by explicitly calculating the fraction i.e.

```
if nnz(A)/numel(A) <= 0.5
   disp('Matrix-A is Sparse Matrix\n');
else
   disp('Matrix-A is Dense Matrix\n');
```

Comment: which more efficient and faster 2 for loop or by nnz function

Comment: I do not understand what you're asking in above comment. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: we can Write a nested for loops to test if an input Matrix A is a sparse matrix or not. or by built-in function as above code by using nnz/numel functions. my question is  Which code is faster? What conclusion can be drawn from this result?

Comment: A nested `for` loop will be an over-kill for this task and nnz/numel functions are way more likely to be better and faster. If you implement it using  nested `for` loops, you'd very  much likely be self-implementing nnz/numel functions. Unless you mex it up, I believe nested `for` loops will remain slower as compared to nnz/numel functions

Comment: thanks for you support but after test for loop and above code this my results
Elapsed time is 0.020615 seconds. - by for loop
 
Elapsed time is 0.033064 seconds. by nnz function

sample array A=zeros(1000,1000);

if array is ones(1000,1000) another result
Elapsed time is 0.039131 seconds. for loop
Elapsed time is 0.008463 seconds.  by nnz

Comment: from above text, it seems that you're using `tic` `toc`. Please note that `tic` `toc` is for rough estimation of time. If you want to compare two codes, use [`timeit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html). Also make sure that you do not have any such process running in the background that may affect it.  If you have a faster/better loop solution, you can post it as an answer so that I may also take a look on your code.